# Putting variable inside array[]

Tags: php

So instead of spending much time explaining i will just show you what the problem is, i have this method

```
public function lockCheck($string)
   {
        $Data = $this->getQuery("SELECT '$string' from settings where id=1");
        if ($Data->num_rows==1)
        {
            while($Row = $Data->fetch_assoc())
            {
                if ($Row[$string]==1)
                {
                    return true;
                }

                else 
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
   }
```

And its working perfectly fine if i dont have a parametar and just use 'locked' which is column from my table. But when i try using parametar $string it will always return false.

And this is how i call the method:

```
$ks->lockCheck("locked")
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Why the single quotes (`'`) around `$string` in `"SELECT '$string' from settings where id=1"`? That's invalid SQL.... It should be backticks (`) if anything

Comment: Remove the single quotes!

Comment: @MarkBaker technically its not invalid, mysql would select the string `'locked'` literally, where id is 1

Comment: @Andrew - true enough, selecting a string literal is valid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your SQL, when you want to avoid to use a reserved keyword, you need to escape your variable wiht ` character, not single quote.

For example:

```
$Data = $this->getQuery("SELECT `".$string."` from settings where id=1");
```

This is also works, but previous I think is more elegant:

```
$Data = $this->getQuery("SELECT `$string` from settings where id=1");
```

Comment: Thanks man i always thought it was single quotes instead of `